# show full stack track in minitest

Tags: ruby, minitest

given the following test:

```
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'

describe 'stuff' do
  def foo
    assert false
  end

  it "should show stack trace" do
    foo
  end
end
```

I am getting an error saying failed assertion on line 6, is it possible to show full stack trace so I know it got called within the it statement?

Comment: have you tried adding `-v` or `--verbose` flag when running?

Comment: yeah, tried those, by default, minitest shows stack trace on error, but line number of failed test on test failure. I think in general they discourage putting assertions into helper methods. The issue is when using capybara heavily, we rely on things such as page.must_have_content for some helper methods to verify the appropriate actions have been performed on the server. For example: def signin(username, password); #login code; click_on "login"; page.must_have_content 'success'; end

Comment: Nowadays the `-b` flag will show the full backtrace. Setting the BACKTRACE environment variable (to any value) will also do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

With default Minitest, you only get the (abbreviated) stack trace when an exception is raised.  Try the [Minitest::Reporters](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters) gem if you want to be able to customize your output easily - including also showing a partial stack trace for failures.

Answer (score 0):

The minitest failure message should show which test has failed - in the case of an exception being raised then a stack trace would be useful.

So, if I add another test calling the `foo` method then I will also see that test fail, and the same line.

```
describe 'stuff' do
  def foo
    assert false
  end

  it "should show stack trace" do
    foo
  end

  it "will not show stack trace" do
    foo
  end
end
```

Then I see;

```
Finished in 0.001372s, 1457.7259 runs/s, 1457.7259 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
stuff#test_0001_should show stack trace [t.rb:6]:
Failed assertion, no message given.


  2) Failure:
stuff#test_0002_will not show stack trace [t.rb:6]:
Failed assertion, no message given.
```

You would generally use a custom method in a test to verify common functionality;

```
it 'works like a Widget' do
  widget = WidgetMaker.do_something
  verify_widget widget
end

private

def verify_widget(widget)
  assert_ # etc ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `-b` is no longer a valid option for `rake test`. I'm running `minitest (5.13.0)`.

Use `-t` instead:

```
rake test -h
...
-t, --trace=[OUT]   Turn on invoke/execute tracing, enable full backtrace. OUT can be stderr (default) or stdout.
```

Answer (score -1):

As @Rafael mentioned in the comments, there's the `-b` flag.

This flag is added by the rails extension to minitest, so it is a minitest option, but requires rails.

The correct order of the options is this:

```
rails test -b #...
```

Check it by calling the help:

```
> rails test -h
Usage: rails test [options] [files or directories]

You can run a single test by appending a line number to a filename:

    rails test test/models/user_test.rb:27

You can run multiple files and directories at the same time:

    rails test test/controllers test/integration/login_test.rb

By default test failures and errors are reported inline during a run.

minitest options:
    -h, --help                       Display this help.
        --no-plugins                 Bypass minitest plugin auto-loading (or set $MT_NO_PLUGINS).
    -s, --seed SEED                  Sets random seed. Also via env. Eg: SEED=n rake
    -v, --verbose                    Verbose. Show progress processing files.
    -n, --name PATTERN               Filter run on /regexp/ or string.
        --exclude PATTERN            Exclude /regexp/ or string from run.

Known extensions: simplecov, minitest_reporter, rails, pride
    -w, --warnings                   Run with Ruby warnings enabled
    -e, --environment ENV            Run tests in the ENV environment
    -b, --backtrace                  Show the complete backtrace
    -d, --defer-output               Output test failures and errors after the test run
    -f, --fail-fast                  Abort test run on first failure or error
    -c, --[no-]color                 Enable color in the output
    -p, --pride                      Pride. Show your testing pride!
```

Comment: what do you mean by "nowdays"? I'm getting usage message:

```
invalid option: -b

minitest options:
...
```

Comment: @ishefi I corrected and extend the explanation, hope it helps.